# React conditional rendering height issues

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My app uses a fair amount of conditional rendering within a  element. The issue that I keep running into is that the form doesn't recognize the height of the conditionally rendered portions. Additionally, the 2 buttons I have at the bottom of the form show an incorrect height in the dev console. From what I can tell, the form height seems to cut off after the first conditional. I feel like I'm missing something here, but just can't figure it out. Little snippet of the button code and style below.

```
<div className={classes.btnDiv}>
    <Button
        className={classes.resetBtn}
        vaiant="contained"
        color="default"
        onClick={handleResetBtnClick}
    >
        Reset
    </Button>
    <Button
        className={classes.submitBtn}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
    >
        Start
    </Button>
</div>
```

The styles are:

```
btnDiv: {
        marginTop: "8px",
        minHeight: "30px"
    },
submitBtn: {
        width: "45%",
        fontWeight: "600",
        backgroundColor: "#02578e",
        float: "right",
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: "#213455"
        }
    },
    resetBtn: {
        width: "45%",
        fontWeight: "600",
        backgroundColor: "#d6d9db",
        float: "left",
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: "#949baa"
        }
    },
```

Let me know if the conditionals would be useful to see...I left them out because they're just `{boolean && <a few components>}`

Comment: Does this have to do with conditional rendering or CSS? Would be easier if you provided a working jsfiddle example. I would start by removing floats and either add a height to the container and put height 100% on the buttons, or set the height of the buttons and the container should match the height of it's children.

Comment: @StefanBob I think you're right about this being a CSS issue, which honestly makes sense because I'm somewhat of a CSS newb. Removing the floats fixed the height. Why in the world would that happen though? Lemme see about a jsfiddle example. Never done one of those so might take a sec

Comment: floating elements removes them from the normal flow of the document, i.e. it no longer takes up space. Imo floats are not needed anymore with flexbox and should be avoided.

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I'll take a look at flexbox and how I can work it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly enough, this isn't a react issue (thanks @StefanBob!). It's actually just my mediocre CSS skills at work! The reason things weren't showing correctly was because of various `float` attributes in the form's CSS. Removing the floats caused everything to play nicely height-wise. Take a look at the post comments to see their explanation.